# Règles pour ajouter "de" aux noms étrangers

Tags: usage, prononciation, noms-propres

À la radio, j'ai souvent entendu « Donald **de** Trump » ou « David **de** Cameron » — ou sans le « de ». Ceux qui ajoutent « de » prononcent aussi les noms plus « français ». Je ne me souviens pas de cas où « de » a été ajouté au nom de quelqu'un qui n'est pas politicien. Est-ce que c'est seulement pour des hommes d'état ? Et qui parle comme ça ? Les « patriots », les plus vieux, un groupe différent, ou il n'y a pas de groupe spécial ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une confusion. Personne ne dit « Donald de Trump » ou « David de Cameron ».

C'est tout simplement le « d » final de ces prénoms qui est un peu trop appuyé. C'est souvent le cas avec l'accent méridional.

Comment: Comment ? on n'a pas Barrak de Obama ?

Comment: @Archemar Non, c'est **Barack que Obama** !